# Android studio layout resource for screens with height bigger than width

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, screen

In android studio I know that, for example if I will create a folder with name *layout-sw600dp*, the layout files inside that folder will be used for screens with minimum of 600dp width. I want to know is there a way to name a folder, which will be used for screens with height bigger than width? And if there is no way, how to create behavior like that(i.e. separate layouts for screens with height bigger than width and with width bigger than height)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can measure device's height and width with this code:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_activity, null); 
//For example, linear layout
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.yourlinearlayout);
linearLayout.measure(0,0); 
int width = linearLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = linearLayout.getMeasuredHeight();
if(width > height) {
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folder name `layout-port` - indicating that the device is in portrait mode (taller than wide) or `layout-land` for landscape mode (wider than tall).

See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) for more information on the available options.

Comment: Could there be devices with a width greater than the height in portrait orientation, and devices with a height greater than the width in portrait orientation?

Answer (score 0):

There are some screen sizes with width longer than height (tablets for example).
you can check the screen aspect in xml using the "-long" "-notlong" suffix in your layout folder.

> This is based purely on the aspect ratio of the screen (a "long" screen is wider). This isn't related to the screen orientation.

```
>long: Long screens, such as WQVGA, WVGA, FWVGA
>notlong: Not long screens, such as QVGA, HVGA, and VGA
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources